# Using regex to get concatenated string from long newline separated list

Tags: regex, arrays, string, list, text

Assuming i got really really large list of random numbers in a text file each entry separated by newline how do i construct a xml structure.

#### Source

```
6253266057
3970002069
6837266077
...
```

#### Result wanted

```
<Random value="6253266057" />
..
```

I did string replace on Source but then it `complained of unclosed string` since last quote would have to be in last line making other entries look abandoned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some programming languages or even text editors you can replace:

```
 ^(\d+)$
```

with

```
 <Random value="\1" />
```

Where `\1` is matching number

Comment: +1 thanks. I was using the Notepad and foolish to think it had regex replace.